# synchronise git repo with private repo

Tags: git, github

I have forked a private repository, on which I only have view rights.

When I want to resync master locally I do

```
git remote add upstream [private's url repo]
git pull upstream master

// => remote Repository not found.
```

Is there a solution to synchronise the repository, or should I ask for more privilege to the owner of the private repo?

Thank you

Comment: Repository not found usually means that the URL is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To always keep upstream repository you can add a git-hook. For example you can `git pull upstream master` after every commit in your local repository. You dont need priviledge to stay updated. Maybe you could need some priviledge to `push`, just because you are not the owner.